# URI scheme is not "file". Unable to read file from classpath

Tags: java, java-io, file-handling, vfs

I have Java webapp and I am trying to read a file from classpth.

```
 if (fileName == null){
        fileName = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("config.properties");
    }
objFile = new File(fileName.toURI());
```

I have config.properties in my classpath. WEB-INF/classes. When I inspect locally it gives: `fileName.toURI()`, it gives me `file:/D:/dev/Tomcat_6_0/webapps/testApp/WEB-INF/classes/config.properties`. And works fine.

Issue is on production linux server I am getting this path there `vfsfile:/export/home/u/bin/jboss-5.1.0.BE/server/default/deploy/testApp.war/WEB-INF/classes/config.properties`.

And I am getting following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:366)
    at com.utils.ConfigLoader.loadConfigFilePath(ConfigLoader.java:87)
```

What is the workaround for handeling vfs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not try to convert a resource from the classpath to a File. It may not even be a File if it's inside a WAR/JAR. The File class only represents filesystem objects.

Comment: Yes, it is in my war. Is it good if I change string vfsfile:/ to file:/ in File constructor?

Comment: No. If it is not a file on disk -- and it isn't -- then `File` cannot represent it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're loading resources (and they may be or may not be files, just imagine this properties file packed into jar/war), why don't you use `openStream()` on URL object? Then just read contents out of BufferedStream returned and that is it!